# C# basic Object and Classes

Tags: c#, class, object, inheritance

I have posted my code below.

My problem is program crashes when Im using:

```
myCarLabel.Text = MyCar.ToString();
```

What did I do wrong ?

I want to output the values from `MyCar.Brand` and `MyCar.Year` into the myCarLabel .

it works using:    myCarLabel.Text = comboBoxBrand.Text + "\n" + comboBoxYear.Text;

but then I lose the whole point using my classes and so on..  any suggestions ?

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    // GetVehicleInfo() ska returnera värdena från MyCar
    public string GetVehicleInfo()
    {
        return Brand + "\n" + Year;
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string Kolor { get; set; }
}


private Car MyCar;    

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    MyCar = new Car();
    MyCar.Brand = comboBoxBrand.Text;
    MyCar.Year = comboBoxYear.Text;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // comboBoxBrand.Text + "\n" + comboBoxYear.Text;

    myCarLabel.Text = MyCar.ToString();
    myCarLabel.BackColor = colorDialog.Color;
}
```

Comment: Subject line is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site, and the question does not provide information such as what the exception is or what the values of the variables are at the point of the exception.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Where did you define the function MyCar,ToString()?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: is your Form1_Load correctly subscribed to Form.Load event

Comment: i dont see MyCar being initialized, not any exception handling. Hence your program is bound to crash

Comment: First off, if you do not override the ToString() method in you MyCar class, it is going to return a string value of "Car", not the data member values.  I am sure that is not what you want.

Comment: since we don't have much to work off, my guess is NullReferenceException on myCar possibly because the Form_Load isn't actually linked to (usually done by designer) so if you just copy and paste the user code it wont.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean by "program crashes", but looking to you code it appears you should do:

```
myCarLabel.Text = MyCar.GetVehicleInfo();
```

You are not overriding the ToString method. The default ToString implementation will return some metadata about the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Crash can be realted to 1000 things. In your concrete example, it **may** be related to a fact

```
myCarLabel.Text = MyCar.ToString();
```

- or `MyCar` is null
- or `myCarLabel` is null
- or both of them

In addittion, I don't see override of `ToString(..)` method in your class, for example:

```
class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string Kolor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
          return Kolor;
    }
}
```

Those are just basic examples, of what you **may** need, it's hard to deduct something concrete from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Vehicle
{
     public Vehicle()
     {
         // do instantiations here so that none of your members are null
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return Brand + "\n" + Year;
     }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
     public Car() : base()
     {
         // Note that the base default constructor is called with : base()
         // then perform Car-specific instantiations here.
     }
     ...
     public override string ToString()
     {
         // Now, you can refer to the super class's ToString() if you want to.
         return base.ToString() + "\n" + Kolor;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inherit too, on `Vehicle` class override `ToString()` (like on example) when you to make this, the `Car` class will use the function `ToString()` on `Vehicle` class, because actually, the `Car` class using function `ToString()` on `Object` class. Finally you no need to use the expression `MyCar.Tostring()`, just use `MyCar` like on line 4 in the function `button1_Click` (myCarLabel.Text = MyCar)

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    // GetVehicleInfo() ska returnera värdena från MyCar
    public string GetVehicleInfo()
    {
        return Brand + "\n" + Year;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return GetVehicleInfo();
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string Kolor { get; set; }
}


private Car MyCar;    

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    MyCar = new Car();
    MyCar.Brand = comboBoxBrand.Text;
    MyCar.Year = comboBoxYear.Text;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // comboBoxBrand.Text + "\n" + comboBoxYear.Text;

    myCarLabel.Text = MyCar;
    myCarLabel.BackColor = colorDialog.Color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For locating the cause of the crash, here are a couple checks:

- Make sure that the `Form.Load` event is properly set to your method and being called. You can set a breakpoint (**F9**) on the first line or bracket inside `Form1_Load` to make sure it gets hit.
- Set a breakpoint on the line `myCarLabel.Text = MyCar.ToString()`. Mouse-over both `myCarLabel` and `MyCar` to ensure that they are not null in the debugger.

As for improvements to your code, here are some:

First, you have not overriden `ToString()` on either `Car` nor `Vehicle` classes. While this is not required, your `ToString()` method will return a rather meaningless `YourNamespace.Car` string here. Consider adding an override:

```
public override string ToString()
{ 
  // Format this however you'd like:
  return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Year, this.Brand);
}
```

Secondly, you are create your `Car` instance inside of the `Form.Load` event which means that changes to the `ComboBox` are not reflected in your object. So if the users changes the selected *Brand* or *Year*, it will not update the object. Consider moving it to the `Button.Click` event:

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var car = new Car();
  car.Year = yearComboBox.Text;
  car.Brand = brandComboBox.Text;

  myCarLabel.Text = car.ToString();
  myCarLabel.BackColor = colorDialog.Color;
}
```

Also, you do not need to store a `Car` as a member variable for this. If you need a custom dialog or `Form` for adding/editing car entries, it would be better to create methods that return a `Car` or have a similar property on the custom `Form`. For example:

```
void addCarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var dialog = new AddCarForm();
  var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

  if(result != DialogResult.OK) return;

  var newCar = dialog.Car;

  // Do something with the newly created car.      
}
```

However, if you must keep the member variable, it should start with a lowercase letter `myCar` instead of `MyCar` to avoid confusion with properties, constants, and methods.

Answer (score -1):

You have to override the toString() Method of your class

```
        public override string ToString()
    {
        return comboBoxBrand.Text +"\r\n"+comboBoxYear.Text;
    }
```

Comment: He does not __have__ to. `ToString()` will always return the `Type.FullName` property by default ("Namespace.Car" in this case).

It will not crash the program for a missing `ToString()` override.

Answer (score -1):

i don't see MyCar being initialized, not any exception handling. Hence your program is bound to crash

Comment: -1 look at Form1_Load event

Comment: @eklam: assuming the designer has added the event handler for this. it could be that the OP hasn't (for example, copied and pasted just the user code)